# Strange characters when booting ubuntu 14.04.2 with TEXT mode

Tags: 14.04, text, mode

i've installed xubuntu 14.04.2 desktop x86 on my laptop. i changed /boot/grub/grub.cfg to have it booting with TEXT mode.

everything works find but one: strange characters are shown before showing login prompt.

what can i do to avoid this? I use ubuntu for my commercial customers who complaint with this...

many thx!

[image: STRANGE CHARACTERS]

Comment: i'm a linux developer in both C/C++ and bash/initrd.lz, so any detailed/programming advice would be appreciated~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think that this is related to software problem or OS problem at all, I think that your graphic card is at the end of life. Three days ago card on my laptop died and it was showing same characters on display, they appeared in BIOS and when starting system, and GUI can't even start any more. I hope that I'm wrong but...

Comment: that sounds bad to be from BIOS... i'll ask my customer to change another laptop with the same vendor/model. try try see...

Comment: wait... I member another thing. i use the exact system on a hyper-v 2012 virtual machine, and it shows the same characters: also from virtual machine BIOS?

Comment: I didn't experienced this problem on virtual machines that I run, but did on a couple of laptop and desktop computers.

Comment: on hyper-v 2012 vm, strange characters are shown only when booting with TEXT mode (add "text" to grub2 cmmand line), but not with graphics mode. what kinds of laptop/pc are experiencing such problem? all with old graphics cards?

Comment: In my case all with broken cards, not old or new, I was working in computer service before I started to work as system admin at faculty.